# Fetching all entities with many to many relationships in repository layer : Hibernate with JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

in my current project, I am using Hibernate with JPA.

I have entities as follows:

Entity A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Association> associations = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Entity B:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "b")
    public class B implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;

        @OneToMany
        private Set<Association> associations = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

Entity Association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "association")
public class Association implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    B b;

   ...other columns..
 }
```

Now I would like to implement repository layer for A as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {

    //Here I would like to write the function/query get all the As with many-to-many relationships.

}
```

Comment: If you want to get all A with the mapped objects, just call findAll() method of repository, this method is provided by CRudRepository, so you don’t have to write any method or if you want to get by id then you need write a custom method on your repo like getById(long id) and rest things will be taken care by JPA. And your mapper object will not be loaded eagerly since default fetch type is lazy, so you have to call getB() on A object and getAssociation() on B objects

Comment: You can refer: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa